# Is ruby 2.7 and earlier code compatible with ruby 3.0.1?

Tags: ruby, upgrade, backwards-compatibility

I'm having difficulty deciding whether to build a new ruby gem in ruby 3.0.1 vs ruby 2.7. Is ruby code written in versions >=3.0.0 backwards compatible with versions >=2.5 or >=2.7? Can somebody working in ruby 2.7 consume a gem written in >=3.0.1, on the same note can someone working in >=3.0.1 consume a gem written in ruby 2.7? Are there any breaking changes in 3.0.1 that make it difficult to upgrade from 2.7?

Comment: Generally speaking the answer is: it depends. Obviously 3.0 is a major release and thus it has implemented syntax features and Object methods that are not supported by < 3.0 but there are plenty of features and methods that remain unchanged. Can 2.7 consume a gem written in 3.0.1? It depends the gemspec may set qualifying ruby version so if this is set to >= 3.0 then no otherwise maybe (See answer 1.) Can 3.0.1consume a gem written in 2.7? (See Answer 2)

Comment: Are there breaking changes that make it difficult to upgrade? It depends 3.0 implemented some changes that may make it difficult (especially if you ignored previous deprecation warnings). Read more [here](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html) and decide for yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is ruby code written in versions >=3.0.0 backwards compatible with versions >=2.5 or >=2.7?

No. For example:

> Other notable changes since 2.7. Keyword arguments are separated from other arguments. In principle, code that prints a warning on Ruby 2.7 won’t work.
>
> https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/12/25/ruby-3-0-0-released/

However, it is possible to write a library using the *subset* of Ruby that is compatible with 2.5 through 3.0. For example, PaperTrail aims to do this.

```
# https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/.github/workflows/test.yml#L66
ruby: [ '2.5', '2.7', '3.0' ]
```